# Custom delete in ASP.NET Dynamic Data scaffolds

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

How could I implement a custom delete operation in a  `ASP.NET Dynamic Data Project`? 
I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341920/understanding-the-delete-link-in-asp-net-dynamic-data-scaffolds) but nothing helped. Here's the block of code for the `delete command`:

[image]

If I implemented the `GridView1_RowCommand` event I can catch it on the debugger, but where does the actual `Delete` command code stored, and if I changed the commandName to `newDelete` how to implement a custom delete query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RowCommand` event to gridview and write custom code for deletion

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "newDelete ")
    {
      e.CommandArgument // will Return current Row primary key value
        ..............
      //Write Delete custom code here
      .............
    }
}
```

Comment: and if i have multiple tables in my Dynamic data then I have to rewrite the query for each table? and i have to filter of the `table.Name` property of the `protected MetaTable table;`  lets say i want to unite the deletion for all tables so instead of deleting the row i want to set the field `IsDeleted = true` foreach table I have in my DD, is that aprochable without rewriting code for each table?

Comment: yes, let's say you have parent and child table which have column IsDeleted and you want, when you delete and set the status in parent column then child tables will automatically update with the status? IF that is the case, then you can do this in DB and set on update Cascade similary we use for actual deletion on Cascade Delete child record.

Comment: No Muhammad, Lets say that I have 3 separated tables, if i want to implement custom delete process then i have to re-write the `deletion code` three times (I have three tables), what i was asking is there away to unite this so i just write the code once and it will suit all tables!?

Comment: As you want to implement custom Deletion, you have to update the these tables.

Comment: You have not set the DataKey property of Gridview to your primary key column.

Comment: It does't matter, just set DataKeyName="PrimaryKeyColumnName"

Comment: i cant since its used for multiple tables (Dynamic Data Web Site), but when i was watching the `GridView1.DataKeyNames` it was bounded to the current selected table's primary key, this is weird!

Comment: e.CommandArgument only returns value, if you set the DataKeyName, otherwise you have to think alternate way to get the value.